# Устранение Memory Leak

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти

Я начинающий програмист, использующий С++(с надеждой в дальнейшем попасть в GameDev). Так вот, для собеседования была написана игра и хотелось устранить все утечки, но хоть я и проверил, что бы всем new соответствовали delete, но все же функция _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); выдает три точки утечки памяти, и я не могу их устранить. Может ли что то, кроме new спровоцировать утечку?

Update: Поставил vld(visual leak detector), он не находит утечки, вышеуказанная функция всё еще кричит о трех утечках

Comment: `_CrtDumpMemlryLeaks` обычно вызывают только на самом последнем этапе жизни программы. Эта функция говорит о неосвобождённой памяти, но это ещё не значит, что следующей строчкой кода ее не освободят. Например все глобальные статические объекты будут почти всегда показываться этой функцией. Но эта функция настраивается с помощью `_CrtSetDbgFlag`, надо смотреть нужные флаги.

Comment: Valgrind Вам в руки. Если Вам удобны обычные указатели - будет с ними осторожны. Или используйте smart pointers